# Parse Error: Line 1: Illegal import declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I created a React application with the code in a file called `App.jsx` that starts like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';
```

When I do `npm run` I get:

```
> 1 | Parse Error: Line 1: Illegal import declaration
    |       ^
  2 | for file /path/to/file/App.jsx
```

I looked online and it appears that the `import` statement is not recognised unless I use Babel.

However, from what I understand, with the new Create React App https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html there is no need for Babel.

So what's the best way of solving this issue?

Comment: From the documentation: "You’ll need to have Node >= 4 on your machine.". I'm betting you don't.

Comment: Yes, I do have Node >= 4....

Comment: Node does not support `import`, so it sounds like Babel hasn't been enabled properly?

Comment: Check out the git page importing components. https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#importing-a-component

Answer (score 1):

In the `.eslintrc` file, enable modules via `ecmaFeatures: { modules: true }`

See [Illegal import declaration - Issue #2112](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2112) for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

From the link:

> Create React App uses both Webpack and Babel under the hood.

As the current browsers don't support the *import* statement, you have to use Babel or similar

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add Babel to your project because it is already included in the development environment provided by create-react-app. However, you can't just run your files directly. You have to use it as it is suggested in the blog post you linked in your question.

Comment: So how exactly do I have to use it?

Comment: @octavian `npm start`

Comment: That's exactly the problem. `npm start` generates files with the error above